# View Binary Logs of GCP Postgres SQL instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, binary-log

How to view Binary Logs(Transaction Logs) of a GCP Postgres SQL Instance? Can it be viewed in GCP Console?

I tried to use Stackdriver. But it only shows instance usage data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The transactions (among a log of other things) are kept in the WAL, which you can look at (partially) using the provided tool [`pg_waldump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgwaldump.html), which shows the contents in a more human readable way, e.g.:

```
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     54/    54, tx:    1123429, lsn: 28/0BC386A0, prev 28/0BC38580, desc: LOCK off 10: xid 1123429: flags 0 LOCK_ONLY EXCL_LOCK , blkref #0: rel 262581/261781/274824 blk 0
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):    401/   401, tx:    1123429, lsn: 28/0BC386D8, prev 28/0BC386A0, desc: UPDATE off 10 xmax 1123429 ; new off 16 xmax 0, blkref #0: rel 262581/261781/274824 blk 1, blkref #1: rel 262581/261781/274824 blk 0
rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):     64/    64, tx:    1123429, lsn: 28/0BC38870, prev 28/0BC386D8, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 19, blkref #0: rel 262581/261781/274826 blk 1
rmgr: Gin         len (rec/tot):    270/   270, tx:    1123429, lsn: 28/0BC388B0, prev 28/0BC38870, desc: UPDATE_META_PAGE , blkref #0: rel 262581/261781/274827 blk 0, blkref #1: rel 262581/261781/274827 blk 2
rmgr: Transaction len (rec/tot):     34/    34, tx:    1123429, lsn: 28/0BC389C0, prev 28/0BC388B0, desc: COMMIT 2019-03-08 16:31:54.832416 CET
rmgr: Standby     len (rec/tot):     50/    50, tx:          0, lsn: 28/0BC389E8, prev 28/0BC389C0, desc: RUNNING_XACTS nextXid 1123430 latestCompletedXid 1123429 oldestRunningXid 1123430
rmgr: Standby     len (rec/tot):     50/    50, tx:          0, lsn: 28/0BC38A20, prev 28/0BC389E8, desc: RUNNING_XACTS nextXid 1123430 latestCompletedXid 1123429 oldestRunningXid 1123430
rmgr: XLOG        len (rec/tot):    106/   106, tx:          0, lsn: 28/0BC38A58, prev 28/0BC38A20, desc: CHECKPOINT_ONLINE redo 28/BC38A20; tli 1; prev tli 1; fpw true; xid 0:1123430; oid 282777; multi 2; offset 3; oldest xid 561 in DB 1; oldest multi 1 in DB 1; oldest/newest commit timestamp xid: 0/0; oldest running xid 1123430; online
rmgr: Standby     len (rec/tot):     50/    50, tx:          0, lsn: 28/0BC38AC8, prev 28/0BC38A58, desc: RUNNING_XACTS nextXid 1123430 latestCompletedXid 1123429 oldestRunningXid 1123430
rmgr: Heap2       len (rec/tot):     59/  4643, tx:          0, lsn: 28/0BC38B00, prev 28/0BC38AC8, desc: CLEAN remxid 1123429, blkref #0: rel 262581/261781/274824 blk 0 FPW
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     65/  6525, tx:    1123430, lsn: 28/0BC39D28, prev 28/0BC38B00, desc: UPDATE off 7 xmax 1123430 ; new off 17 xmax 0, blkref #0: rel 262581/261781/274824 blk 1 FPW
```

For a better introduction into how to read the WAL contents, have a look it this neat little presentation: [WAL: Everything You Want to Know](https://www.slideshare.net/EnterpriseDB/postgres-vision-2018-wal-everything-you-want-to-know)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find binary logs in the GCP Console because Postgres itself does not use binary logs.

Perhaps [this post in ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/54380/how-do-mysql-logs-compare-to-postgresql-logs) may be useful for you to do some further reading.